# responsive design @media break points not working

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm new to @media and am having some difficulty setting up my breakpoints. I've got a mobile first site with 4 columns and a footer that I want to have different views for mobile, desktop/tablet landscape, and desktop/tablet portrait.

```
<body style="margin:0;padding:0">

<div class="col-d2" style="float:right">
<h1 style="text-align:right;display:inline;margin:0">title</h1>
<nav id="burgerbtn">sitemap/menu
   </nav>
</div>

<div class="col-d4 lfloat" style="margin:100px 0"><div id="lcontent">
 content1
</div></div>

<div class="col-d4 lfloat" style="margin:100px 0"><div id="rcontent">
content2
</div></div>

<div id="paton" class="col-d2 column lfloat bar" style="background:yellow">
sidebar
</div>

<div style="background:green;clear:both;text-align:right">foot</div>
</body>
```

**For mobile I'd like the following to stack for mobile:**
 
 sitemap/menu 100%
 content1 100%
 content2 100%
 sidebar 100%
 foot 100%

**For landscape:**

 sitemap/menu 16.66%
 content1 33.33%%
 content2 33.33%%
 sidebar 16.66%
 foot 100%

**And for portrait:**
 
 sitemap/menu 100%
 content1 50%
 content2 50%
 sidebar 83.33%
 foot 100%

Here's my css which is basically a copy/paste template with some changes:

```
/* For mobile phones: */
[class*="col-"] {
    width: 100%;
}
@media screen and (min-width:950px) and (orientation:landscape){
    /* FOR DESKTOPS */
    .col-d1{width:8.33%}
    .col-d2{width:16.66%}
    .col-d3{width:25%}
    .col-d4{width:33.33%}
    .col-d5{width:41.66%}
    .col-d6{width:50%}
    .col-d7{width:58.33%}
    .col-d8{width:66.66%}
    .col-d9{width:75%}
    .col-d10{width:83.33%}
    .col-d11{width:91.66%}
    .col-d12{width:100%}
.column{min-height:975px}
.lfloat{float:left}
.rflex{display:flex;display:-webkit-flex}
.cflex{flex:auto}
#sitemap{margin:150px 0 0}
#rcontent{padding:0 50px 0 25px}
#lcontent{padding:0 25px 0 50px}
#paton{margin:0 !important}
}
@media screen and (orientation:landscape){
    /* LANDSCAPE */
    .col-land1{width:8.33%}
    .col-land2{width:16.66%}
    .col-land3{width:25%}
    .col-land4{width:33.33%}
    .col-land5{width:41.66%}
    .col-land6{width:49%}
    .col-land7{width:58.33%}
    .col-land8{width:66.66%}
    .col-land9{width:75%}
    .col-land10{width:83.33%}
    .col-land11{width:91.66%}
    .col-land12{width:100%}
}
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) and (orientation:portrait){
    /* FOR TABLETS: IF TIME ALLOWS */
    .col-tab1{width:8.33%}
    .col-tab2{width:16.66%}
    .col-tab3{width:25%}
    .col-tab4{width:33.33%}
    .col-tab5{width:41.66%}
    .col-d4{width:50% !important}
    .col-tab7{width:58.33%}
    .col-tab8{width:66.66%}
    .col-tab9{width:75%}
    #paton{width:83.33%}
    .col-tab11{width:91.66%}
    .col-d2{width:100% !important}
.bar{text-align:center}
}
```

I can get 2 break points to work (landscape and mobile or portrait and mobile) but never all 3 to work. Little help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Oh duh. Ok. Moving the added css out of the @media screen landscape makes it work. I had initially only planned 2 breakpoints so it didn't matter, but with 3 it does. Final css:

```
/* For mobile phones: */
[class*="col-"] {
    width: 100%;
}
@media screen and (min-device-width:950px) and (orientation:landscape){
    /* FOR DESKTOPS */
    .col-d1{width:8.33%}
    .col-d2{width:16.66%}
    .col-d3{width:25%}
    .col-d4{width:33.33%}
    .col-d5{width:41.66%}
    .col-d6{width:50%}
    .col-d7{width:58.33%}
    .col-d8{width:66.66%}
    .col-d9{width:75%}
    .col-d10{width:83.33%}
    .col-d11{width:91.66%}
    .col-d12{width:100%}
}
@media screen and (orientation:landscape){
    /* LANDSCAPE */
    .col-land1{width:8.33%}
    .col-land2{width:16.66%}
    .col-land3{width:25%}
    .col-land4{width:33.33%}
    .col-land5{width:41.66%}
    .col-land6{width:49%}
    .col-land7{width:58.33%}
    .col-land8{width:66.66%}
    .col-land9{width:75%}
    .col-land10{width:83.33%}
    .col-land11{width:91.66%}
    .col-land12{width:100%}
}
@media screen and (min-device-width:650px)and (orientation:portrait){
    /* FOR TABLETS: IF TIME ALLOWS */
    .col-tab1{width:8.33%}
    .col-tab2{width:16.66%}
    .col-tab3{width:25%}
    .col-tab4{width:33.33%}
    .col-tab5{width:41.66%}
    .col-d4{width:50%}
    .col-tab7{width:58.33%}
    .col-tab8{width:66.66%}
    .col-tab9{width:75%}
    #paton{width:75.33%}
    .col-tab11{width:91.66%}
    .col-d2{width:100%}
.bar{text-align:center}
}

.column{min-height:975px}
.lfloat{float:left}
.rflex{display:flex;display:-webkit-flex}
.cflex{flex:auto}
#sitemap{margin:150px 0 0}
#rcontent{padding:0 50px 0 25px}
#lcontent{padding:0 25px 0 50px}
#paton{margin:0 !important}
```